# Говорить о бреде / говорить в бреду

Tags: орфография, склонение, существительные

> Говорить в бреду

Второе склонение. Предложный падеж.

> Говорить о бреде

Второе склонение. Предложный падеж.

Почему разные окончания, если падеж одинаковый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[БРЕД](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4) — существительное, мужской род, неодушевлённое, второе склонение.

Все правильно: **о бреде** (о чём?), но **в бреду** (где?).
У некоторых слов мужского рода нулевого (второго) склонения есть так называемый **местный** падеж (или второй предложный, или локатив) — после локативных предлогов **в** и **на** употребляется особая форма предложного падежа.
Эта форма характеризуется особыми окончаниями:
***в шкафу, в лесу, на берегу, в носу, во рту, на лбу, в бою.***

[Второй предложный](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6#12)

*Если я заболею,

к врачам обращаться не стану,

Обращаюсь к друзьям

(не сочтите, что это **в бреду**):

постелите мне степь,

занавесьте мне окна туманом,

в изголовье поставьте

ночную звезду.*
Ярослав Смеляков

Comment: Понятно, это разные падежи значит. Предложный-1 и предложный-2. Тогда остается последний вопрос 'но в бреду (где?)' почему не 'но в бреду (в чём?)'. Или это одно и то же?

Comment: Ведь если спросить (в чем) то как раз получается обычный предложный - в свитере, в пледе, в бреде. Почему не пользуются стандартным предложным, говоря в чем? - в бреде

Comment: Локативная форма употребляется не со всеми предлогами, управляющими предложным падежом, а только после **в** и **на**. Теоретически Вы можете задать вопрос _в чём?_ Но ответить Вы должны _в бреду._ (Такая форма встречается лишь у **небольшой группы** неодушевленных существительных 2-го и 3-го склонения в единственном числе.)

Comment: Ладно, буду отвечать в свитеру и в пледу :)

Comment: Зачем же Вы ТАК? Просто слова "свитер" и "плед" НЕ ВХОДЯТ в указанную группу: о чём? — о свитере; в чём? — в свитере; на чём? (где?) — на свитере.

Comment: Спасибо, я думал все существительные второго склонения входят в ту группу, а варьируемость окончания опциональна (в зависимости от вопроса где или в чем). Но теперь вижу, что дело не в вопросе. В чем - в шкафу, а не в шкафе. Теперь совсем все понятно, спасибо.